# How to generate a low disk alert for an Azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

i have an virtual machine (which am using as build server) which disk gets piled up frequently and am working on fixing that, mean while am looking for options to setup an alert to be fired when my disk space gets high.

i checked the available metrics under monitoring but could only find "disk write bytes" and "disk read bytes" which are not helpful for me.

i will need help on setting a disk space alert to be sent to my email.

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: You can follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68482941/how-to-create-azure-monitor-alert-when-my-disk-space-low-in-virtual-machine.

Answer (score 4):

> i will need help on setting a disk space alert to be sent to my email.

For now, Azure does **not** support monitor Azure VM disk space, we can use `shell` or `PowerShell` to monitor VM disk space and send email to you.

Here a example about Linux VM(**ubuntu**), we can create a `sample.sh` then add it to `cron`.

sample.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT=$(df / | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
THRESHOLD=90

if [ "$CURRENT" -gt "$THRESHOLD" ] ; then
    mail -s 'Disk Space Alert' youremail@domainname.com << EOF
Your root partition remaining free space is critically low. Used: $CURRENT%
EOF
fi
```

Add it to `cron`, add it to `crontab`:

```
*/60 * * * * /home/jason/sample.sh
```

**Note**:

we should install mail on this VM with this script:`apt install mailutils`.

By the way, if you don't want to install mail on your VM and don't want to use VM to monitor itself, we can create another VM and install `Zabbix` or other monitor tools to monitor Azure VMs disks space.

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure [OMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/operations-management-suite/operations-management-suite-overview). There is a [example](http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/cfuller/archive/2016/02/08/using-oms-to-visualize-server-health-based-on-free-disk-space/) how to use Azure OMS to monitor free disk.

Comment: Hi, Am looking for something to setup in azure portal under virtual machines or something that can be done inside the server since this will be specific to one server for now.