# Valid list of alert conditions for Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm trying to create an alert for low disk utilization. And I see the syntax given in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/alert?view=azure-cli-latest#az_monitor_alert_create) which checks for CPU utilization.

`az monitor alert create -n rule1 -g {ResourceGroup} --target {VirtualMachineID} --condition "Percentage CPU > 90 avg 5m"`

I can't find a list of possible conditions I can enter so that I can give the correct command for low disk utilization.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to list the affected resource available metrics definitions of the resource with:

```
az monitor metrics list-definitions --resource [TARGET_ID] | jq '.[].name'
```

you can list the target_id's of the resource with:

```
az resource list | jq '.[].id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible. You could check supported-metrics in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftcomputevirtualmachines).

[image]

But you could do it with Azure OMS, you could check this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853392/monitor-free-disk-space-on-azure-vm).

Comment: Maybe you also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47536304/how-to-generate-a-low-disk-alert-for-an-azure-virtual-machine/47547103#47547103

Answer (score 0):

you can use this PowerShell command to list all available metrics for the specific resource/resource type
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azmetricdefinition?view=azps-6.4.0)

```
Get-AzMetricDefinition -ResourceId <>
```