# How to create azure monitor alert when my disk space low in virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-monitor

I have one virtual machine . Now I want if my disk space showing very low I mean less than 2 gb. Then I want to trigger azure monitor alerts and want to get Email regarding this. is there any metrics azure monitor provide.

Comment: Not a specific answer to your question but we've found Azure Monitor painfully useless when it comes to sending alert emails. Both myself, and our Azure CSP (i.e. supposed MS-endorsed Azure experts) have been unable to find a way to include anything more useful that the ResourceID in the emailed alert. We've opted for a Free PRTG install instead which is far easier to install and configure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no predefined alerts for diskspace as of now . But you can create a new alert with custom log search to get the details and then trigger the email to you.

**Step 1 :** Go to Alerts on your Monitor Page and click on New alert rule .

[image]

**Step 2:** Then select the resource and by resource here you have to select the Log analytics workspace which you have enabled the VM monitoring for . In my case its TestLog.

[image]

**Step 3:** Now select the Custom Log Search .

[image]

**Step 4:** Then provide the Custom Query which I have provided below in the search query box and you can set the threshold value to “0” and period and frequency in mins as per your requirement for an example I have set it to 60mins.

[image]

**Step 5:** Now Select an existing Action group that you have or you can create a new one by clicking on create new and filling the details . After its Created click on the action group and add the notification type as Email or anything you want to specify.

[image]

[image]

**Step 6:** Fill rest details like email subject and severity of the alert you want to set it to and then create alert.

[image]

**Custom Query:**

```
let setgbvalue = 200;//Set the disk space you want to check for. 

 Perf 

 | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)

 | where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "Free Megabytes" 

// exclude all others as we are checking for C: here 

 | where InstanceName != "D:"  

 | where InstanceName  != "_Total" 

 | where InstanceName != "HarddiskVolume1" 

 | extend FreeSpaceGB = CounterValue/1024 // converting the counter value to GB 

 | summarize FreeSpace = min(FreeSpaceGB) by Computer, InstanceName 

 | where FreeSpace < setgbvalue //setting condition to check if the value is less than our set value .
```

[image]

**Sample :**

To test it I had set the value to 200GB and my disk space was 106GB. I received the mail as below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much you provide me what exactly i am looking.

Comment: I have followed all steps but I am not getting email. Also my Logs query returning me :  "No results found from the specified time range"  .  My "C:" Drive space is 109 GB free of 126 GB.

Comment: Please enable guest agent metrics and add perf counters , if not added by default while creating..

Comment: Yes It's Working now.

Comment: I keep getting no records found and diagnostics are enabled and performance counters too?

Comment: Hello @itye1970, May I know what are specifications of your VM? if you have followed the above steps or not?

Comment: Good to hear that !